# Merging repository as branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Is it possible to merge one repository, that contains only one branch, into other as branch (and save all changes history)?

Im using github, so, if you can, it would be very kind if you can give specific directions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Add second remote and merge the branches from the remotes

```
# add remote 
git remote add <remote2> <url2>

# checkout the desired branch (from any remote)
git checkout master

# merge the second remote branch to it
git merge remote2/branch_name
```

---

[image]

Comment: im getting "nothing to merge" after writing this in gitshell